# How to compile c++ code with system() function (MSVC)?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

i am trying to compile a c++ file with system() function using c++.

```
void CodeGenerator::GenerateExe(ProgramNode* parsed_tree, std::string folder_path, std::string file_name)
{
    std::string cpp_name = folder_path + file_name + ".cpp";

    GenerateCppFile(parsed_tree, cpp_name);
    std::string command;
    command += "cl ";
    command += cpp_name + " /OUT ";
    command += folder_path;

    system(command.c_str());
}
```

I know I can do that in developer cmd, but the system() function opens regular cmd, so it cannot recognize the "cl" command.

Please tell how to open developer cmd or how to setup the environtment to compile the code via c++.

Comment: cl.exe must be in path in order for it to run. You also need to set the environment with vcvarsall.bat (which is the one that executes when you open the developer command prompt in Visual Studio)

Comment: you need at first know path to *CL.exe* and not use *system* but *CreateProcessW*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding the path of `cl` to the environment variables:

This can be done like so:

- Open a run window, you can do this by typing `run` in search.
- type `sysdm.cpl`
- Choose Advanced separator
- Click environment variables
- In system variables select `path` and click `edit`
- Click `new` and add the path of your `cl` command. In my case the `cl.exe` file is in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\Hostx64\x64`

It doesn't vary all that much but you must use the correct path in your machine.

- After this you must open a new cmd window for the changes can be detected and run the `cl` command from any place in your machine.